# How to Resolve Clojure Cake Compile Error

Tags: clojure, pom.xml

[Mea Culpa I pointed to Clojure 1.3, not Clojure 1.3.0.]
I just downloaded the latest Clojure jar file, 1.3.0. I have a simple cake project, which is now throwing a missing artifact error

```
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
```

What do I need to add to my project.clj file

```
(defproject repl-test "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
   :repositories {"clojure-snapshots" "http://build.clojure.org/snapshots"}
   :main repl-test)
```

or what do I need to build to fetch this missing artifact?

I have made sure the clojure-1.3.0.jar file is installed.

If this is a POM problem, I'm not sure what command to run to install the artifact.

Comment: btw: CakePHP is a PHP MVC web framework, it doesn't have anything to do with Clojure or the Clojure build to cake.

Comment: Also: clojure-contrib 1.2.0 may not work with clojure 1.3.0, the new contrib is modular, find more documentation [here](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib).

Comment: As an aside, when you get a long error message you don't understand (and Maven is certainly famous for this), it's better to [gist](https://gist.github.com) it than to extract the part you think is important. In this case > 1 required artifact is missing.
> > for artifact: org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0 is not at all useful, but the full error message would contain enough information to make it clear that the missing dependency was Clojure itself. For example, here's [the output I get](https://gist.github.com/11abfee25f23c90c10c2) with a similar `project.clj`. In this output `org.clojure:c

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about gist.

Comment: Turning clojure 1.3 into 1.3.0 was the problem, and the other suggestions are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `[org.clojure/clojure "1.3"]` with `[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]` then this should work.